# join all text files in subfolders in ubuntu into a single file

Tags: linux, files, cat

I have many folders/subfolders with text files in them.
Is there any way to iterate all of the subfolders and join all the files into a single large file?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One simple way:

```
find /top/level/subdir -type f -exec cat {} + > output
```

Or using bash features:

```
shopt -s globstar
cat subdir/** > output 2>/dev/null
```

The 2>/dev/null redirection drops the complaints about bash trying to `cat` directories.

Comment: by output you mean 
output.txt?

Comment: you didn't specify a filename; you can name it whatever you want! :)